# libinput touchpad is always ON with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, libinput

I have a Lenovo L540 with trackpoint and touchpad. My system is Ubuntu 18.04 up to date. I would like to switch the touchpad off. I found that if I go to system settings - Mouse & Touchpad, I can switch off the touchpad. The touchpad is now OFF.

But after suspend or restart, the touchpad is working again and under system settings I see that touchpad is ON. I must switch it off again.

Is there any way to keep the touchpad switch off permanent?

Comment: you're using a dev version so file a launchpad bug

Comment: I don't understud why my question is closed!! I don't use a developmet version. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 standard.

Comment: Well you said in question "My system is Ubuntu 19.04 ",  was that an unfortunate typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time always manuel shut the touchpad off I found a solution. I use the TouchPad Indicator and set there the trackpoint on and the touchpad off.
Hope this info helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I found an Archlinux article about disabling the touchpad with **xinput**.
1. Get its name with `xinput` list.
2. Disable it with `xinput disable <device name>`.

For more information, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput#Disable_touchpad.

Comment: Hello Dominik, thanks for Your answer. I tried it. It completely disable the touchpad and I can't use the keys which work still if I disable the touchpad using system settings. Remember I have a Lenovo laptop and use the trackpoint which have no mouse keys.

Comment: So you just want to disable the touchpad despite the keys? This might be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156949/how-to-keep-the-touchpad-but-want-to-deactivate-the-buttons

Comment: Hello Dominik, I take a look at question 156949. I see no help in that.